# Cannot Reverse the list for newly added (Firebase Realtime Database)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am displaying latest added posts, and for that to achieve, I am using the following code:-

```
Query ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Rules")
                .child(category)
                .orderByKey()
                .startAt("25")///This is the child name i am getting by some other method
                .endAt("30")///This is the child name i am getting by some other method
                .limitToLast(6);

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: "+ dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    sortsearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    list = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        list.add(ds.getValue(Deal.class));

                    }

                    try
                    {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Collections.reverse(list);///Using to Reverse the list
                                try
                                {
                                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            adapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            adapterClass =new AdapterClass(list);
                                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
                                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                                        }
                                    }, 1000);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e){

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                else{

                    nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sortsearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    TextView failedform = findViewById(R.id.failedform);
                    failedform.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    searchbynamesearchview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

In the above code i am using Collections.reverse method to reverse the list, but when i add 6 more posts, it is not getting reversed with the same method. Below is the method i am using to load more 6 posts recently posted:-

```
Query ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Childname")
                .child(category)
                .orderByKey()
                .endAt("24")///This is the child name i am getting by some other method
                .startAt("19");///This is the child name i am getting by some other method


        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                final Deal post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Deal.class);
                Collections.reverse(list);

                list.add(post);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
                adapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                nextpage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                loaderloadmore.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: There is an error");
            }
        });
```

I also used the below method to reverse my list, they are working, but upon loading more posts they are getting added at top of the list, i want to add the results of loadmore at the bottom:-

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearLayoutManager lv =new LinearLayoutManager(this);
lv.setReverseLayout(true);
lv.setStackFromEnd(true);

options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Modelclass>().setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post").orderByChild("rating"), Modelclass.class).build();
```

By adding lv.setReverseLayout(true);
lv.setStackFromEnd(true); to your code you get reversed list.

This will reverse the order of RecyclerView so you don't need to change the order of data.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you're making it way more difficult than needed.

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            sortsearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            list = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                list.add(0, ds.getValue(Deal.class));
            }

            adapterClass =new AdapterClass(list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        }
        else{

            nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sortsearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TextView failedform = findViewById(R.id.failedform);
            failedform.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            searchbynamesearchview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

By using `list.add(0, ds.getValue(Deal.class))` you add each subsequent item to the start of the list, effectively reversing the item order.

---

If you want to add more nodes to the end of the list in reverse order, it's easiest to do it as a two-step process:

1. Get the items into a new list in the reversed order with the approach outlined above.
2. Append the items from this list to the original list as they are.

Something like:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Rules")
            .child(category)
            .orderByKey()
            .startAt("25")
            .endAt("30")
            .limitToLast(6);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List newList = new LinkedList();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            newList.add(0, ds.getValue(Deal.class));
        }
        list.addAll(newList);
        adapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged(); // tell the adapter to repaint
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, i don't need to reverse by using 'list.add(0, ds.getValue(Deal.class))' but when i click load more items are being added at the top or start as you said above, but that is the problem here, i need to get reverse result but also need to add items at the bottom. 
   **For example** i have post named from One - Ten, I am loading onstart only 5 in the reverse order:- Ten,Nine,Eight,Seven,Six, Now i want to load more in reverse order to start from bottom to keep the sequence of the posts.

Comment: In that second query, you should also: 1) remove the call to `Collections.reverse(list);`, 2)  use `list.add(0, post);` to ensure they're added to the start.

Comment: your suggestion `list.add(0, post);` i used after your first reply already for the second query, but the second query is being added in the first query, that's why it was adding to the top again, but anyway thanks for your suggestion about the one line code `list.add(0, post);` i used this and for the second query i am using the actual position in ur suggested code like this `list.add(7, post);` where i am incrementing the position (7++) on each load. Am i doing right ??

Comment: You should never need an explicit index like that for pagination. As far as I can see you should always add them to the start (with `0`), or to the end.

Comment: So How to add the more added posts to the bottom with reverse order??

Comment: `DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.packagename.ui.rules.functions.Deal' i got this error, while using your method to add more results to recyclerview